# Angular 4 Forms Validators Regex Patern method

Tags: angular, angular2-formbuilder

I am trying to use this regex pattern within my Form Builder Group.

```
DataLocationFolder: ['', [Validators.pattern('/^(\\(\\[^\s\\]+)+|([A-Za-z]:(\\)?|[A-z]:(\\[^\s\\]+)+))(\\)?$/')]],
```

This should match against a valid path (c:\) or valid UNC path (\\xzxzx). I have run the code on Regex101 and it works as expected.

However when I Load the webpage that uses this this particular form it errors with:

> ConfigurationComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR SyntaxError:
>   Invalid regular expression:
>   /^/^(([^s]+)+|([A-Za-z]:()?|[A-z]:([^s]+)+))()?$/$/:
>   Unterminated group

Comment: Looking at the error I'd say you don't need /^ and $/, since they are added from the pattern function. (note the double /^/^ and $/$/ in the error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try removing the `/`:

```
Validators.pattern('^(\\(\\[^\s\\]+)+|([A-Za-z]:(\\)?|[A-z]:(\\[^\s\\]+)+))(\\)?$')
```

or alternatively the `'`

```
Validators.pattern(/^(\\(\\[^\s\\]+)+|([A-Za-z]:(\\)?|[A-z]:(\\[^\s\\]+)+))(\\)?$/)
```